# Ubuntu 20.04lts, cron -l fails Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: command-line, cron

I'm getting this:
Cron won't list current jobs, ie `sudo cron -l` fails. It returns:

```bsh
can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 468110: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I've tried the following steps:

```bsh
sudo kill -9 $(cat /var/run/crond.pid)
```

```bsh
$ ps aux | grep $(cat /var/run/crond.pid)
root        1322  0.0  0.0   9412  3096 ?        Ss   Feb15   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

```bsh
$ sudo service cron stop
$ sudo service cron start
$ sudo cron -l
cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 468110: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The status of cron:

```bsh
sudo service cron status
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-02-16 18:20:06 PST; 1min 40s ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 467956 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38312)
     Memory: 484.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─467956 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

The task gets locked immediately with a new PID, so something is grabbing it right away.
I also haven't actually added any cron tasks myself, however I do have clamav installed and it has a freshclam task associated with it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `crontab -l`?

Comment: I'm doing a system audit looking for any signs of cron jobs added, crontab seems like it only looks at the current user.  Perhaps there is a way to see everything?

Comment: I'm not aware of a one-shot way to do that, but `crontab` accepts a `-u user` option so for example `sudo -u someuser -u` (looped over users)

Comment: You are experiencing normal, expected behavior. See `man cron`. Particularly "*cron  then wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs, checking each command to see if it should be run in the current  minute.*" It does not keep track of jobs; it simply matches. To see the jobs, you must read each crontab file.

Comment: In this case I can run it every few seconds and the lock remains.  The original lockfile and PID stay around, so it's not a new process as anacron is running.  Perhaps this is just the way anacron handles it, as a constant service?

Comment: Regardless of how often you run `cron -l` it is not the correct command to list cron jobs. See the man page for cron. You are confusing it with `crontab -l`. There is no way to make cron list all its configured jobs. Some exist in files like ```/etc/crontab``` and in files beneath directories ```/etc/cron.d/```, ```/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}/```. Others are associated with particular users. These latter ones can be shown with ```crontab -u <user> -l``` or by looking at files under ```/var/spool/cron/crontabs/```. There is no command that lists every single one of both types.

Comment: I think this may end up being helpful to others, @grifferz could you turn this into an actual answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `cron -l` is not the correct command to list cron jobs. See the man page for cron. I think you are confusing it with `crontab -l`.

There is no way to make `cron` list all its configured jobs. Some exist in files like `/etc/crontab` and in files beneath directories `/etc/cron.d/`, `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}/`. Others are associated with particular users. These latter ones can be shown with `crontab -u <user> -l` or by looking at files under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`.

There is no command that lists every single one of both types